# Search SQL table depending on logged in user?

Tags: c#, sql

Each user has a UserID and when that user logs in I need it to search that table called 'Audit_Tasks' and anything with there ID next to it needs to show up on there listbox.

At the moment I have just attempted to pass the logged in user to the class:

```
    public partial class xamlAgentDashboard : Window
{
    cAuditUserEntity _loggedInUser;
    public xamlAgentDashboard(cAuditUserEntity loggedInUser)
    {
        _loggedInUser = loggedInUser;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

This is the table I am looking to call, Lets say user 1002 just logged in I need to call that database and bring back; transactionId, tasktypeid and display that in that users listbox:

[image: table details]

```
public partial class xamlAuditorDashboard : Window
{
    cEvolve_SP sp = new cEvolve_SP(Properties.Settings.Default.AppConnectionString);
    List<cAuditTasksEntity> _tasks;
    cAuditUserEntity _loggedInUser;
    public xamlAuditorDashboard(cAuditUserEntity loggedInUser)
    {
        _loggedInUser = loggedInUser;
        InitializeComponent();
        Refresh();
    }

    private void Refresh()
    {
        var _AuditUserId = _loggedInUser;
        cAuditUserEntity user = _AuditUserId as cAuditUserEntity;

        int userid = user.AuditUserId;

        _tasks = new List<cAuditTasksEntity>();

        _tasks = sp.GetTasksByUser(userid);
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? Your current headline does not qualify.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch My Question is depending on the user logged in. How can i automatically search a table and get just there information and display in a listbox

Comment: select * from table where userId = @loggeduser?

Comment: A lot depends on how you are identifying the user in both your application and your database. Is this all Windows security? Are you connecting to the database with a service account or a trusted connection that has the user's security? Is this a web app or a windows app? Need much more detail.

Comment: @jean will edit my question now so ou understand sorry

Comment: @Bill Will edit the question now

Comment: Given your answers, go with jean's suggestion. Just make sure the ID used to save the record matches the ID used to retrieve it.